# Copying AD group members to another AD group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to copy all members from one AD group to another.  The code I am using is failing.

Caveat: The members in the source group are from different (trusted) domains.
I am not a Powershell expert.

Example code:

```
$Source_Group = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "CN=Team1_ReadOnly, 
OU=Team1,OU=TEAM_GROUPS,OU=Groups,OU=Business,DC=Server1,DC=Contoso,DC=com" 
-Server "Server1@contoso.com"
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity " CN=Team2_ReadOnly, 
OU=Team2,OU=TEAM_GROUPS,OU=Groups,OU=Business,DC=Server1,DC=Contoso,DC=com " 
-server "Server1@contoso.com" -Members $Source_Group
```

Error Output:

[image: Error Output]

Has anyone come across this issue before with users from different domains?

We have moved all users who are in the same domain as the destination group without issue in the past.

Comment: This script only failed because it was unable to get the group members and store them in `$Source_Group`. Confirm that command works correctly. I would double check what you provided `-Identity` and `-Server` are correct. In your example you are specifying the same domain so it is not really a good test. If you can populate `$Source_Group` correctly then your Add-ADGroupMember might work just fine.

Comment: I can’t screen shot the output as it contains sensitive data.   But I can confirm that using the following code structure does produce an output from the variable:
    $Source_Group = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "CN=Team1_ReadOnly, 
    OU=Team1,OU=TEAM_GROUPS,OU=Groups,OU=Business,DC=Server1,DC=Contoso,DC=com" 
    -Server Server1@contoso.com
    Write-host "VarOutput : $Source_Group"

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question.

The code was fine.  It turns out the person (DBA) running the script was running it directly from the target domain controller.  The target domain controller did **NOT** have a trust with a particular domain that one of the members was attributed to.  I tested from my local machine that had rights across all domains.

When the script was run on a machine that had a trust with all domains it worked fine.